# Wordpress Open Social Error:"Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"

Tags: php, wordpress, opensocial

I am using the **Open Social Plugin** in **Wordpress**. I also installed the Debug Plugin to see what is going on. I get a **PHP Error** saying:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /wp-content/plugins/open-social/open-social.php on line 111.

**Line 111 in open-social.php:**

```
'google'=>"http://translate.google.com.hk/translate?hl=".(isset($_SESSION['WPLANG_LOCALE'])?$_SESSION['WPLANG_LOCALE']:'en_US')."&sl=zh-CN&tl=".(isset($_SESSION['WPLANG_LOCALE'])?reset(str_split($_SESSION['WPLANG_LOCALE'],2)):'en')."&u=%URL%"
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this line? I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
reset(str_split($_SESSION['WPLANG_LOCALE'],2))
```

You are trying to `reset` the return value of `str_split`; you can only `reset` a variable, not an expression value. See [**the docs for `reset`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php), which show that it is declared as `mixed reset (array &$array)`.

It's not 100% clear to me what you are trying to do with `reset` here. I suspect you just want the `str_split` value, in which case you don't need to `reset` anything.

Comment: Thank you. I guess locales are given in the format `en_us` for example and this line is trying to chop of en _us and wants the first part of the  `str_split` array If i get this right -> `en`

Comment: I replaced `reset` with this: `(str_split($_SESSION['WPLANG_LOCALE'],2)[0])`. It should do the same?

Comment: Yeah, that does look like what you want. Just drop the `reset` and you should be okay.